# Linux - new hard drive, bad magic number in superblock

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning

**SOLUTION**: For all of the things that were right, making the *volume* with `fsck` and making the *filesystem* with `mkfs` are two *separate* operations. Thanks for giving me nice, descriptive, *helpful* error messages, Linux. :D

---

```
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
```

That error occurred when running `sudo fsck /dev/sda` on a brand new drive. I ran `sudo fdisk /dev/sda` and added a new partition (just accepted the defaults here) but I got a corresponding magic number error when trying to mount it. I tried alternate blocks (using superblocks listed by `sudo mkfs -n /dev/sda`) but none worked, they were all listed as being corrupt.

I'm looking for a way to solve this, especially considering it's a brand new drive, never partitioned.

Addendum 1: After this failed, I `dd`'d the entire disk with zeroes, then used `fdisk` and noted it had no partitions. I added a partition in `fdisk` (accepting the defaults). In `fdisk`, partitions are listed as follows:

```
Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x639543e8

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048  3907029167  1953513560   83  Linux
```

I then used `sudo mount /dev/sda1 drivefolder/` and it gave the following error:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 drivefolder/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

The `dmesg` output shows this:

```
[17467275.127319] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[17467275.127325] ata9.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[17467275.127332] ata9: EH complete
[17594695.132437]  sda: sda1
```

And `fsck` says:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.23.1
e2fsck 1.42.7 (21-Jan-2013)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
```

Since this was a new drive, and I also `dd`'d the entire drive to zeroes, I'm at a loss to fix it. It's reproducible and so far the solutions I've seen involve using the `fsck -b` option, but I've tried it with all of the backup superblocks given by `mkfs` and none of them have worked.

Comment: Had this _brand new drive_ ever had any data or volumes on it before you started `fsck`ing it?  If not, what error, exactly, do you think that there is to solve?  The inability to repair a volume that was never there in the first place is not an error.  Or rather, the error lies in thinking that it is.

Comment: I created a volume using `fdisk` and then tried to mount that volume, and it complained about a bad superblock. See appended section I'm adding to the question.

Comment: So I tried the whole process (wipe with `dd`, make volume with `fdisk`, try to `mount` the new volume, no dice). `fsck` still reports a bad superblock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you did a `mkfs /dev/sda1`, when you mount it, you have to use `mount /dev/sda1 /wherever`, not `mount /dev/sda /wherever`.

---

To add a volume to `fstab` so it automatically mounts on boot, first find its UUID using `blkid`:

```
# blkid /dev/sda1
UUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX /media/whatever          ext2    noatime
```

and conveniently you can just add that entire line to your `fstab` - with the exception that you probably want to change the 2nd parameter that tells it where to mount it.  Don't mount things to `/media` with `fstab` - make a directory in `/mnt` or similar.

On Debian and Debian derived distros such as Ubuntu, symlinks to each attached physical drive's `/dev/sdX1`, etc. are in `/dev/disk/by-id` - these symlinks will have recognizable names based on the bus and manufacturer of the drive.  Use the UUID for fstab because it will always work.

Comment: I'm using `sudo mount /dev/sda1 drivefolder/`

Comment: Waitaminute. Just looked up `mkfs` - that's the problem. In the article I used, they used `mkfs -n /dev/sda` to show alternate superblocks for `fsck`. But I needed to run `mkfs /dev/sda1` to actually _make the filesystem_. Apparently `fdisk` creates the volume, but not the filesystem. *DERP* The more you know, right?

Comment: And one quick additional question... I'm adding the drive to the fstab file to mount on boot. On Mac OS X, all drives map to `/Volumes/NameOfDrive/` - is there an equivalent on Linux? The closest I can find is `/media` but that seems like it would be more for external/removable drives.

Comment: Check out my edit.

Comment: Thanks, `/mnt` seems like the right place.